# ipscanner на python3 (модуль ipaddress). вывод - все хосты в оффлайне

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу код, одной из функций которого является сканирование диапазона адресов, введенных пользователем в виде: `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX_start-XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX_end`

Отработал код  на локальной сети и получил в качестве результата все хосты в оффлайне.

Сам код:

```
import os, ipaddress

position_start = input('Start hostname: ')
position_end = input('End hostname: ')

hostname_start = ipaddress.IPv4Address(position_start)
hostname_end = ipaddress.IPv4Address(position_end)

while hostname_start <= hostname_end:
    hostname_response = os.system("ping -c 1 -w 2" + str(hostname_start)+ "> /dev/null 2>&1")
    if hostname_response == 0:
        print (hostname_start, ' is up!\n')
    else:
        print (hostname_start, ' is down!\n')
    hostname_start += 1
input("\nPress the enter key to exit...")
```

Вот, например, код, где я работаю напрямую ip-адресом в виде строки, он исполняется отлично

```
import os

hostname = "8.8.8.8" #example
response = os.system("ping -c 1 -w 2 " + hostname)

#and then check the response...

if response == 0:
  print (hostname, 'is up!')
else:
  print (hostname, 'is down!')
```

Думаю, что проблема в модуле ipaddress, но не могу понять где.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена.

Пропущен пробел после параметра `-w 2`:

```
hostname_response = os.system("ping -c 1 -w 2" + str(hostname_start)+ "> /dev/null 2>&1")
```